# How can I use the Linux System Rescue CD to backup my windows partition to another computer over a SMB network?

Tags: linux, networking, backup, samba

I would like to back up a partition over a network, as it's just a bit too big for a CD. I downloaded the Linux System Rescue CD, seeing that it can do stuff similar to that, but I can't figure out how to quite go the distance to get it to work correctly...

My network currently consists of:

1. 2 Windows XP machines (One of which is the computer I'm wanting to partition).
2. 2 Windows 7 machines.

I know the networking is a bit easier for Windows XP than Windows 7, so I've already created a share point on the spare Windows XP machine to copy the share to.

Specifically, I'm struggling with the following:

1. How to I mount the network share from a linux command prompt?
2. Is Partimage the correct tool to use for this purpose?
3. How do I tell Partimage to use the now mounted SMB share as it's location to store?

Comment: Using samba, you'd mount the drive like "sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME ON COMPUTER,password=PASSWORD ON COMPUTER //192.168.1.56/C$" This is the same for both windows 7 and XP, linux doesn't care. I've mounted both, I'm not sure about the other questions, though.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Clonezilla? http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php Best way is to create a Live USB. You will be able to mount your Windows share as part of imaging process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to figure this out, after I put it into words exactly what I needed to do, and with some help from Rob as well.

1. First mount the network drive. I did the command `mount -t cifs \\192.168.1.102\Linux_Share /mnt/Linux_Backup/`
2. When you specify the name of the file in partimage, specify the full path, ie, /mnt/Linux_Backup/WindowsXP/
3. Partimage seems to work just fine for me.